# Create custom OData previouslink in WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, odata, atompub

I have a WebApi OData API.
I want to perform some pagination. I have managed to fill the nextlink since it exists in OData.

```
public IQueryable<Product> Get(int min=0,int max=0)
    {
        this.Request.ODataProperties().NextLink = new Uri(Url.ODataLink(
              new EntitySetPathSegment("Products"),
                       new KeyValuePathSegment(Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.ODataUriUtils.ConvertToUriLiteral("100", Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataVersion.V3))
         ));
        ///more code.....
}
```

The problem is that like I can set the NextLink i want to do the same with a PreviousLink (AtomPub)

Is that possible with OData?
How can I create that custom field?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I feel like the construction of this URL should be done on the client rather than the server. I think that the next link is really only there to hint that you haven't actually got all of the data and show that there are more pages

Comment: Hi, i am implementing atompub, so the clients needs to know there are previous items